# Determining available runtime attributes for a UI element in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I've been playing around with a button in my storyboard, and had a hard time getting a border around it, until I found a page where it showed how to add a User Defined Runtime Attribute. I was able to make the button look as I wanted, but I wanted to know if there was a way for me to view the list of available attributes for a particular Object.

[image]

Clicking the "+" to add a new attribute doesn't provide any kind of auto-complete to show the available ones, and looking through my project code doesn't seem to reveal anything either, not surprisingly. Is there somewhere I can find all of the available attributes for all/any Objects in Xcode? Searches here on SO and in general have not shown any useful results so far.

Comment: You can achieve the same thing from code, so just check the properties of `UIButton` (which is available in the documentation and with autocomplete) and you're good.

Comment: `UIButton.` doesn't have a "layer" attribute or "borderWidth"... what am I missing there?

Comment: You are probably trying to use `UIButton.layer` instead of `UIButton().layer`. Both are instance properties and not class properties, so you need to access them through an instance.

Comment: `UIButton` has [`layer` inherited from `UIView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622436-layer).

Comment: @JoshCaswell I did find layer in UIView, but it still has no borderWidth property, at least not on [this page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622436-layer)

Comment: [CALayer().borderWidth](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410917-borderwidth), [CALayer().cornerRadius](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410818-cornerradius)

Comment: I guess if it's just an inheritance tree issue, I can dig deep enough to find it, but that was really the crux of the issue, knowing where/how to find what all my available options are.  Plus realizing I was trying to look at Class properties and not Instance ones (Thanks @DávidPásztor)

Comment: @JoshCaswell Thanks -- again I guess I'm not sure how I would have gotten to CALayer documentation from where I was looking... I'll keep treading through though... Thanks!

Comment: Apple's documentation has never been very good at helping you find things like this. (And they made it significantly worse last year.) Good luck.

Comment: Haha, thanks, I'm glad it's just not me!

Comment: @DávidPásztor your comment was the solution I was looking for -- if you want to post that as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: @TimS. posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same thing from code, so just check the properties of `UIButton` (which is available in the documentation and with autocomplete) and you're good.

You also have to make sure you are checking the properties on an `UIButton` instance and not the class properties.

Answer (score 1):

User defined runtime attribute is a list of key paths that NIB loading subsystem uses through unarchived process. After initialisation message -setValue:forKeyPath: will be send to your unarchiving object for each key path from this list. So available attributes are not more than set union of all methods with selector sort of -setAttribute: and ivars with "_attribute" or "attribute" name.
All that public attributes you may find at public headers or documentation.
There's also possible to set private attributes, but it's not good practice. For instance, you may find all ivars by breakpoint execution inside any method and look inside "self".